# Spring RestTemplate : get with nullable paramaeter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm trying to make a true RestFull service and keeping to the documentation.  However I'm stuck now with a problem I can't see a clear answer for.  I want to use a filter to query some data from the webservice.  The following path is defined on the controller of the webservice

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/postalcode/list/filter?lang={lang}&postalcode={postalcode}&country={country}&city={city}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody JsonPostalCodeList findFilteredPostalCodes(@PathVariable("lang") String lang, @PathVariable("postalcode") String postalcode, @PathVariable("country") Long country, @PathVariable("city") String city, Model model) throws Exception {
}
```

Then I try to call it with the following method on client side

```
public JsonPostalCodeList findPostalCodes(
        JsonPostalCodeSelectorData selectorData) {
    String url = getWebserviceLocation()+"/rest/postalcode/list/filter?lang={lang}&postalcode={postalcode}&country={country}&city={city}";
    MbaLog.debugLog(logger,"Calling webservice with url: " + url);
    return getRestTemplate().getForObject(url, JsonPostalCodeList.class, selectorData.getContactLanguage(), selectorData.getPostalCode(), selectorData.getCountry(), selectorData.getCity());       
}
```

now selectorData.getPostalCode() can be null for example because , the user didn't fill in a postalcode to filter on.  Same can be true for country and city (lang is always filled in).  But each time I run it I get an IOException not found (probably due to the null's).  I tried once with everything filled in and I go perfectly in my method at service side.  So how do you handle such a problem ?

I can solve it by throwing GET out of the window and just put everything in a POST body as a JSONobject mapped with Jackson and problem solved.  But then I'm using a POST to fetch data while a GET should be used in pure REST to fetch data.

So RestTemplate and querying services with variable data how to go about it ?

Comment: can you post full stack trace of the exception here? It might help us in suggestions.

Comment: thnx but I found it out myself, I'm still learning all kinds of stuff regarding to REST.  In my old work I only used SOAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just took a cold shower and found it out myself :)

I don't have to use pathvariables I can just use request parameters.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/postalcode/list/filter", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody JsonPostalCodeList findFilteredPostalCodes(@RequestParam("lang") String lang, @RequestParam("postalcode") String postalcode, @RequestParam("country") Long country, @RequestParam("city") String city, Model model) throws Exception {
}
```

and calling it with

```
@Override
public JsonPostalCodeList findPostalCodes(
        JsonPostalCodeSelectorData selectorData) {
    String url = getWebserviceLocation()+"/rest/postalcode/list/filter?lang={lang}&postalcode={postalcode}&country={country}&city={city}";
    MbaLog.debugLog(logger,"Calling webservice with url: " + url);
    return getRestTemplate().getForObject(url, JsonPostalCodeList.class, selectorData.getContactLanguage(), selectorData.getPostalCode(), selectorData.getCountry(), selectorData.getCity());       
}
```